# Document DB - ST_DISTANCE

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Would a query like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * ST_DISTANCE etc
```

or more specifically

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM c WHERE ST_DISTANCE(c.AssetLocation, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [115.58, 21.84] }) < 49999
```

return the closest object, and if not, how could I order by distance?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Closest to a point that I'd supplied to the ST_DISTANCE function

Comment: no, it will return distance between some arbitrary point in database and yours supplied point, you could order by distance though

Comment: OK thanks for that

Comment: "If you include spatial indexing in your indexing policy, then "distance queries" will be served efficiently through the index." It's easiest to just add a policy on all paths `/*` and let it find spatial data automatically           {
               "kind":"Spatial",
               "dataType":"Point"
            }

Comment: That said, I've only used it in a situation like `ST_DISTANCE(...) < 20`. Never tried using `ORDER BY` and `TOP` on spatial indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DocumentDB does not natively support nearest or ORDER BY using Geo-Spatial index yet.

The best approach for ORDER BY is to project (`SELECT`) the distance in the query and sort it either client-side or via a stored procedure (reduces the latency cost of multiple round trips).

For a large data set, you can optimize nearest by adding a filter (`WHERE`) on distance beginning with a small value, and iterating / stepping through increasing distance values until the first points are found.

Comment: can you please provide me an example of Stored procedure through which i can first calculate distance using ST_DISTANCE and than sort it by distance in document db. Please help me because i stuck in this issue from last week. Thanks !!

Comment: As a more optimistic pattern: I went the other way for a spatial range query - I'm just getting a TOP 100 from the database and filter client-side. If it so happened that I'd get 100 results that indicates I didn't get all results (which is basically never the case), I'm doing some logging and a fallback routine with WHERE conditions kicks in. This allows me to run the optimistic (and far more efficient queries) 99.x% of the time.

Comment: Andrew I want to avoid the cost of complexity of adding such a workaround manually into my application layer. Is it realistic that your team will ship this functionality within this year? Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Andrew, the fact that DocumentDb/CosmosDb doesn't support aliases in WHERE or ORDER BY is quite ridiculous, disastrous for distances, and in fact, it's a showstopper (I'll go to MongoDb or anything NOSQL else). Do you have any roadmap for this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be supported yet (as of 10/10/2018). I'm projecting only the Distance and the Id and then sorting the results client side.Then, I retrieve the top document using the Id.

Comment: ... still not supported - hope you worked around it rather than waiting!