# Order by distance with documentDB api

Tags: geospatial, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get the closest results (by distance) to a point on documentDB, something similar to `$near` in MongoDB.

I tried few variations but keep getting errors/ unsupported messages,
and I feel like I might be missing out the appropriate way.

I know that docDB also has a MongoDB API, is it somehow possible to query this API with `$near` while I'm using the documentDB API?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Azure Cosmos DB: DocumentDB API and you’d like to query the closest/nearest results (by distance) to a point. As far as I know, it supports a number of [built-in Spatial functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#a-idbuiltinfunctionsabuilt-in-functions), but currently it does not support nearest.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262001/document-db-st-distance) discussed a similar issue, and as Andrew Liu said, we could select the distance in the query and sort it either client-side or via a stored procedure to get the nearest point.

Besides, someone has gave a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599050-azure-cosmos-db-documentdb-api/suggestions/11003184-support-order-by-on-the-st-distance-spatial-functi), you could vote it.

Comment: Thanks Fred, i will vote for it. is there are way using the MongoDB API together with the documentDB API?

Comment: When we create Azure Cosmos DB account, we should choose one of [four programming models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqAIv.png): Gremlin (graph), MongoDB, SQL (DocumentDB), and Table (key-value). We can not make a DB support both DocumentDB API and MongoDB API.